# Help! Guitarist stuck on a math(s) problem!

Tags: physics

I'm sure this is embarrassingly basic for the folks around here, but I'm trying to rearrange this equation to give me $uw_2$ - is there anyone who could help? For the record, it's to try and help me figure out the unit weight of a string on a guitar from another string tuned to a different pitch. However, it's the maths bit I'm stuck on! Thanks in advance!

$$ ((uw_1*(2*sl*f_1)^2) / 386.4)/tl_1 - ((uw_1*(2*sl*f_2)^2) / 386.4)/tl_1 = ((uw_2*(2*sl*f_3)^2) / 386.4)/tl_2 - ((uw_2*(2*sl*f_4)^2) / 386.4)/tl_2 $$

Comment: The first thing you can do is factor $uw_2$ out of the right side to get

Comment: You can get the symbol $\times$ by using `$\times$`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've written

$$ ((uw_1*(2*sl*f_1)^2) / 386.4)/tl_1 - ((uw_1*(2*sl*f_2)^2) / 386.4)/tl_1 = ((uw_2*(2*sl*f_3)^2) / 386.4)/tl_2 - ((uw_2*(2*sl*f_4)^2) / 386.4)/tl_2 $$
which I find hard to read. I'm going to replace "sl" with "S", and $uw_1$, etc., with $u_1$, and $tl_1$ with $T_1$, etc., to get

$$ 
((u_1*(2*S*f_1)^2) / 386.4)/T_1 - ((u_1*(2*S*f_2)^2) / 386.4)/T_1 = ((u_2*(2*S*f_3)^2) / 386.4)/T_2 - ((u_2*(2*S*f_4)^2) / 386.4)/T_2 
$$

And since you've asked to solve for $u_2$, I'm going to assume $u_1$ is known. First, let's multiply both sides by $T_1 T_2$ and do some cancelling:
$$ 
T_2((u_1*(2*S*f_1)^2) / 386.4) - T_2((u_1*(2*S*f_2)^2) / 386.4)= T_1 ((u_2*(2*S*f_3)^2) / 386.4) - T_1((u_2*(2*S*f_4)^2) / 386.4)
$$
Now we can expand $(2*S*f_1)^2$ into $4 S^2 f_1^2$, and let $Q = 4S^2$, because it appears so often. Now we have

$$ 
T_2((u_1Qf_1^2) / 386.4) - T_2((u_1Qf_2^2) / 386.4)= T_1 ((u_2Qf_3^2) / 386.4) - T_1((u_2*Qf_4^2) / 386.4)
$$
Phew! It fits on one line now. Now let's factor out some stuff:
$$ 
(T_2 \cdot u_1 \cdot Q)
\left[ \frac{f_1^2}{ 386.4} - \frac{f_2^2}{ 386.4} \right]= (T_1 \cdot u_2 \cdot Q) \left[ \frac{f_3^2}{386.4}- \frac{f_4^2)}{386.4} \right].
$$
Multiply through by $386.4$ to get rid of it everywhere:
$$ 
(T_2 \cdot u_1 \cdot Q)
\left[f_1^2 - f_2^2 \right]= (T_1 \cdot u_2 \cdot Q) \left[ f_3^2-f_4^2 \right].
$$
Do a little division:
$$ 
(T_2 \cdot u_1 \cdot Q)
\frac{\left[f_1^2 - f_2^2 \right]}{ \left[ f_3^2-f_4^2 \right]}= (T_1 \cdot u_2 \cdot Q).
$$
Divide both sides by $Q$:
$$ 
(T_2 \cdot u_1 )
\frac{\left[f_1^2 - f_2^2 \right]}{ \left[ f_3^2-f_4^2 \right]}= (T_1 \cdot u_2 ).
$$
and then by $T_1$:
$$ 
(\frac{T_2}{T_1} \cdot u_1 )
\frac{\left[f_1^2 - f_2^2 \right]}{ \left[ f_3^2-f_4^2 \right]}=u_2 .
$$

That wasn't so bad, was it?

Comment: Why the downvote? The answer is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is amazing! This solves a problem I've been pondering for years :)

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why it got downvoted? It's great!

Answer (score 3):

$$ \frac{uw_1\cdot(2\cdot sl\cdot f_1)^2}{386.4\cdot tl_1 }- \frac{uw_1\cdot (2\cdot sl \cdot f_2)^2)}{386.4\cdot tl_1} = \frac{uw_2 \cdot (2 \cdot sl \cdot f_3)^2}{386.4\cdot tl_2}- \frac{uw_2 \cdot (2 \cdot sl \cdot f_4)^2)}{386.4\cdot tl_2} \implies $$

$$ \frac{uw_1\cdot(2\cdot sl\cdot f_1)^2}{tl_1 }- \frac{uw_1\cdot (2\cdot sl \cdot f_2)^2)}{tl_1} = \frac{uw_2 \cdot (2 \cdot sl \cdot f_3)^2}{tl_2}- \frac{uw_2 \cdot (2 \cdot sl \cdot f_4)^2)}{tl_2} \implies $$

$$ \frac{uw_1\cdot(2\cdot sl\cdot f_1)^2}{tl_1 }- \frac{uw_1\cdot (2\cdot sl \cdot f_2)^2)}{tl_1} =uw_2 \cdot \left[ \frac{(2 \cdot sl \cdot f_3)^2}{tl_2}- \frac{(2 \cdot sl \cdot f_4)^2)}{tl_2}\right] \implies $$

$$ uw_2 = \frac{\frac{uw_1\cdot(2\cdot sl\cdot f_1)^2}{tl_1 }- \frac{uw_1\cdot (2\cdot sl \cdot f_2)^2)}{tl_1}}{\frac{(2 \cdot sl \cdot f_3)^2}{tl_2}- \frac{(2 \cdot sl \cdot f_4)^2)}{tl_2}} \implies $$

$$ uw_2 = uw_1\frac{\frac{f_1^2}{tl_1 }- \frac{f_2^2}{tl_1}}{\frac{f_3^2}{tl_2}- \frac{f_4^2}{tl_2}}=uw_1\frac{tl_2}{tl_1}\frac{f_1^2- f_2^2}{f_3^2- f_4^2}$$

**EDIT:** Just a side note, in future you should use variable names that are shorter, e.g. only one letter. Instead of using unit weight as $uw_1$ you could have written $w_1$, $tl=l$ and $sl=s$. It makes it easier to see what you have to do.

Comment: This is amazing! Thanks so much :) And yep, I hear you on variable names, makes perfect sense! Appreciate the help!

Comment: Can't believe how simple it comes out!

Answer (score 2):

I hit "enter" to get a new line but that posted the comment. I was then told that I could only edit a comment for 5 **seconds**!  So I decided to post the edited version as an "answer":
You can simplify that a lot by factoring out common terms: $\frac{4uw_1sl^2}{386.4tl_1}(f_1^2- f_2^2)= uw_2[\frac{4sl^2}{386.4tl_2}(f_3^2- f_4^2)]$.  Now divide both sides by $\frac{4sl^2}{386.4tl_2}(f_3^2- f_4^2)$.

A lot cancels.